# Safari 7 does not honor the settings from com.apple.Safari.plist file in Mavericks ( OS X 10.9 )

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, safari

I want to allow all plugins in safari. If any user disable the `"Allow plug-ins"` option from `Safari -> Preferences -> Security Tab -> Internet plugins` then programmatically it should be enabled. For that i wrote a sample code which monitors on `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist` file. If the value of key "`WebKitPluginsEnabled`" is changes to No then my program is modify this value to YES and restart the safari to honor the new settings. But however safari does not honor the new settings. After relaunching the Safari Allow Plugins option is disable.

If i change the value from UI then safari works normally. But if I manually edit the `com.apple.safari.plist` file and restart the safari then again safari does not honor the new settings. It loads its old settings.

Same code is working fine in Snow leopard, Lion and Mountain Lion.

So anyone know about how safari stores its preferences in Mavericks(OS X 10.9).
or how to change the preferences of safari programmatically?

Comment: Can you add relative code? Regarding how you change .plist file property.

Answer (score 0):

Although my problem is different - I ended up installing malware that overwrote the default "search engine" and homepage, I do find that Safari does not respect the settings of `com.apple.safari` either. I'm unsure where Safari actually stores its settings as well.

Answer (score 0):

To enable / disable the plugins for apple safari manually / programatically you have to change the following key to true/false in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist file.

To Disable the plugins:

```
<key>com.apple.Safari.ContentPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2PluginsEnabled</key>
    <false/>
```

To enable the plugins:

```
<key>com.apple.Safari.ContentPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2PluginsEnabled</key>
    <true/>
```

I know the answer is bit late :P , But I Hope the above helps you to solve the problem!!